# Insert new record via Liquibase with foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship, sql-insert, liquibase

I am using a Liquibase insert to add two rows to the database and link them via a foreign-key as follow:

```
<changeSet id="1.0.1" author="x">      
    <insert tableName="TABLE1">
        <column name="NAME" value="a value"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="1.0.2" author="x">      
    <insert tableName="TABLE2">
        <column name="FK" valueComputed="(SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = 'a value')"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Both records are correctly inserted, except for the value of the foreign-key in TABLE2. This value remains null. So it seems that the "computeValue" attribute is not correctly executed, but I do not understand why. I would like to have a solution in Liquibase and not in plain SQL since Liquibase offers me the possibility to also easily insert clob fields.

TABLE1:
ID - 5522839049923041049862979858500642751,
NAME - a value

TABLE2:
ID - 4246034635279239656888789950125407204, 
FK - (null)

This is the table structure:

```
<changeSet id="1.0.0" author="x">        
     <createTable tableName="TABLE1">
        <column name="ID" type="NUMBER (38)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="NAME" type="NUMBER (38)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addUniqueConstraint columnNames="NAME" 
        constraintName="TABLE1_UK1" 
        tableName="TABLE1"/>

    <createTable tableName="TABLE2">
        <column name="ID" type="NUMBER (38)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="FK" type="NUMBER (38)">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="FK" 
        baseTableName="TABLE2" 
        constraintName="TABLE2_TABLE1_FK1" 
        referencedColumnNames="ID"
        referencedTableName="TABLE1"/>
</changeSet>
```

Note that a trigger is used to generate the identifiers (primary keys) for the fields named ID when inserting new records in one of the two tables.

Comment: It would be worth getting Liquibase to show the generated SQL, with the `updateSql` parameter. That might give you clue as to what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use predefined values for the primary key and the foreign key?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am using as alternative right now. But this is not the preferred solution.

Comment: hi, guys , do you have some link or advice?, im still looikng for an alternative

Answer (score 0):

If you use sequence than you can use the current value. You can add the id which is created for the last entry of desired table

```
<changeSet id="1.0.2" author="x">      
    <insert tableName="TABLE2">
        <column name="FK" valueSequenceCurrent="table_1_id_seq"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

I know this is not the exact solution for the question but I fixed my problem like this way.